# How do I turn off an Xbox controller when paired using bluetooth?

Tags: controllers, xbox-series-x-series-s

My Xbox wireless controller is connected to my Steam Deck or PC but when I hold down the Xbox button to power it off, it brings up the Steam Deck menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Hold down the Xbox button for [six seconds](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/controller/get-to-know-your-xbox-series-x-s-controller) and it'll automatically power off**
2. Alternatively, remove a battery to turn it off.